# Case expression in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple case expression that runs in SQL Server below. I was expecting to see the result to have over 12 HRS, over 25 HRS, over 45 HRS, and so forth. However, my result returns only over 12 HRS and Less 12 HRS.

```
SELECT
STORE,
CASE
WHEN HOURS >12 THEN 'Over 12 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >25 THEN 'Over 25 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >45 THEN 'Over 45 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >55 THEN 'Over 55 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >75 THEN 'Over 75 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >94 THEN 'Over 94 HRS'
ELSE                'Less 12 HRS'
END                AS HOURS,
COUNT (ID)         AS PRD

FROM
(
    SELECT
    ID,
    STORE,
    HOURS
    FROM TABLE A
)X
GROUP BY STORE,
CASE
WHEN HOURS >12 THEN 'Over 12 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >25 THEN 'Over 25 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >45 THEN 'Over 45 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >55 THEN 'Over 55 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >75 THEN 'Over 75 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >94 THEN 'Over 94 HRS'
ELSE                'Less 12 HRS'
END
```

Comment: because it short-circuits (disclaimer: most of the times). Once it evaluates the first "true" condition, it stops. So try changing the order of your `WHEN`s (WHEN HOURS > 94 ..... WHEN HOURS > 75 ....`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you ordered the cases in the wrong way: when `HOURS >94` is true, `HOURS >12` must also be true, so `HOURS >94` must come before `HOURS >12`.

In general, conditions must be ordered from stronger to weaker, not the other way around.

Reordering the list the opposite way will fix this problem:

```
CASE
WHEN HOURS >94 THEN 'Over 94 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >75 THEN 'Over 75 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >55 THEN 'Over 55 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >45 THEN 'Over 45 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >25 THEN 'Over 25 HRS'
WHEN HOURS >12 THEN 'Over 12 HRS'
ELSE                'Less 12 HRS'
END  AS HOURS
```

Comment: Thanks very much to ALL

Answer (score 0):

The `case` stops at the first matching row, so 13 hours meets the first condition, as does 23 hours, and 75 hours and so on.

You need to reverse the logic.  One simple way is by reversing the comparison order:

```
(CASE WHEN HOURS <= 12 THEN 'Less 12 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 25 THEN 'Over 12 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 45 THEN 'Over 25 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 55 THEN 'Over 45 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 75 THEN 'Over 55 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 94 THEN 'Over 75 HRS'
      ELSE 'Over 94 HRS'
 END) AS HOURS,
```

I would also suggest that you rename the groups.  Something like:

```
(CASE WHEN HOURS <= 12 THEN '00-12 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 25 THEN '12-25 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 45 THEN '25-45 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 55 THEN '45-55 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 75 THEN '55-75 HRS'
      WHEN HOURS <= 94 THEN '75-94 HRS'
      ELSE '94+ HRS'
 END) AS HOURS,
```

Answer (score 0):

25, 45, 55, 75, and 94 are all greater than 12. So that first condition check matches, and there's no need to evaluate any further. You want to write it like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN HOURS >94 THEN 'Over 94 HRS'
  WHEN HOURS >75 THEN 'Over 75 HRS'
  WHEN HOURS >55 THEN 'Over 55 HRS'
  WHEN HOURS >45 THEN 'Over 45 HRS'
  WHEN HOURS >25 THEN 'Over 25 HRS'
  WHEN HOURS >12 THEN 'Over 12 HRS'
ELSE                  'Less 12 HRS'
END
```